# python ignore the separator withing brackets while reading a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am using Python 3.4

I have a CSV file which is comma-separated. So basic csv reader is working fine.

```
import csv

file = "/my/path/test1.csv"

with open(file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(file , delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for line in reader:
        print(', '.join(line))
```

However, data sent (by other system) has a column which is array-like, which is causing the issue.

Data:

```
ABC,PQR,(TEST, TEST2)
FDE,QWE,TRT
```

Expected output:
[image]

Basically comma inside the bracket should not be consider the separator.

Can you please assist in how to achieve this?

Comment: csv reader can handle quotes like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `skipinitialspace` to `True` to skip any whitespace following a delimiter:

```
import csv

file = "/my/path/test1.csv"

with open(file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(file , delimiter=',', quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)
    for line in reader:
        print(', '.join(line))
```

Comment: Thanks @marcuse. How does skipping whitespace helps to ignore brackets? Can you please give some more details.
It worked for my test data, I will try to check for actual data now.

Comment: Glad to help! The skipinitialspace parameter simply says to ignore the comma delimiter if it is followed by a space. In your case with (TEST, TEST2) there is a space after the comma. So the program then ignores the comma as delimiter and redas instead the whole string between the two other delimiter comma's.

Comment: As for the brackets, those are not read in any special way. A list, in which you refer to in your original question, is set between square brackets ['value_1', 'value_b']